How to avoid outer border and modify outer layout of Form using @rjsf/core
I am using Form of @rjsf/core library. Imported the two lib need to be used.
import Form from '@rjsf/core';
import validator from '@rjsf/validator-ajv8';
And using the same as per documentation as below and passing formData, schema, uiSchema.
<Form
  formData={formData}
  onSubmit={onSubmit}
  schema={schema}
  showErrorList={false}
  uiSchema={uiSchema}
  validator={validator}
>
  <></>
</Form>

But getting outer boundary and default fieldSet property of form.
I am using the Form component as per doc but getting outer boundary.
Tried in chrome.
i want no outer boundary. While inspecting getting the boundary by fieldset component used by Form internally.

The outer boundary because of fieldSet of form so we can wrap the Form with a wrapper having required/expected styling

As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
